# Laravel Telescope Jobs __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-telescope

I've installed Laravel Telescope and it works perfectly fine on my local sail instance.

I kept the configuration very default. Just changed the gate and the path to my need.

Path in `config\telescope.php`:

```php
'path' => env('TELESCOPE_PATH', 'admin/telescope'),
```

Gate in `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider`:

```php
protected function gate(): void
{
    Gate::define('viewTelescope', function ($user) {
        return $user->operations()->contains(
            cache()->remember('viewTelescope', 1440, function () {
                return Operation::updateOrCreate([
                    "operation" => "admin/telescope/view",
                    "description" => "Can view Telescope"
                ])->operation;
            })
        );
    });
}
```

However on the stage environment (production look-a-like with `production` tag in `APP_ENV`) I get the following errors in the laravel logs:

Log:

```json
Job is incomplete class: {
    "__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name": "Laravel\\Telescope\\Jobs\\ProcessPendingUpdates",
    "pendingUpdates": [
        {
            "__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name": "Laravel\\Telescope\\EntryUpdate",
            "uuid": "99534bfc-841e-4368-bc84-e495cc38e8b6",
            "type": "job",
            "changes": {
                "status": "processed",
                "updated_batch_id": "99534bfe-1359-4698-a3ce-96701e1de445"
            },
            "tagsChanges": {
                "removed": [],
                "added": []
            }
        },
        {
            "__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name": "Laravel\\Telescope\\EntryUpdate",
            "uuid": "99534bfc-7920-4e0f-b323-27c6accd548f",
            "type": "batch",
            "changes": {
                "id": "99534bfc-7920-4e0f-b323-27c6accd548f",
                "name": "records",
                "totalJobs": 15,
                "pendingJobs": 2,
                "processedJobs": 13,
                "progress": 87,
                "failedJobs": 0,
                "options": [],
                "createdAt": "2023-06-03T22:12:41.000000Z",
                "cancelledAt": null,
                "finishedAt": null,
                "updated_batch_id": "99534bfe-1359-4698-a3ce-96701e1de445"
            },
            "tagsChanges": {
                "removed": [],
                "added": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "attempt": 0,
    "delay": "2023-06-03T22:12:52.783591Z"
}
```

Failed Jobs:

```json
{
    "uuid": "3ab7310f-f531-4d47-bb28-10ec2198d8a0",
    "displayName": "Laravel\\Telescope\\Jobs\\ProcessPendingUpdates",
    "job": "Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
    "maxTries": null,
    "maxExceptions": null,
    "failOnTimeout": false,
    "backoff": null,
    "timeout": null,
    "retryUntil": null,
    "data": {
        "commandName": "Laravel\\Telescope\\Jobs\\ProcessPendingUpdates",
        "command": "O:44:\"Laravel\\Telescope\\Jobs\\ProcessPendingUpdates\":3:{s:14:\"pendingUpdates\";O:29:\"Illuminate\\Support\\Collection\":2:{s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000items\";a:2:{i:0;O:29:\"Laravel\\Telescope\\EntryUpdate\":4:{s:4:\"uuid\";s:36:\"99534bfc-841e-4368-bc84-e495cc38e8b6\";s:4:\"type\";s:3:\"job\";s:7:\"changes\";a:2:{s:6:\"status\";s:9:\"processed\";s:16:\"updated_batch_id\";s:36:\"99534bfe-1359-4698-a3ce-96701e1de445\";}s:11:\"tagsChanges\";a:2:{s:7:\"removed\";a:0:{}s:5:\"added\";a:0:{}}}i:1;O:29:\"Laravel\\Telescope\\EntryUpdate\":4:{s:4:\"uuid\";s:36:\"99534bfc-7920-4e0f-b323-27c6accd548f\";s:4:\"type\";s:5:\"batch\";s:7:\"changes\";a:12:{s:2:\"id\";s:36:\"99534bfc-7920-4e0f-b323-27c6accd548f\";s:4:\"name\";s:7:\"records\";s:9:\"totalJobs\";i:15;s:11:\"pendingJobs\";i:2;s:13:\"processedJobs\";i:13;s:8:\"progress\";d:87;s:10:\"failedJobs\";i:0;s:7:\"options\";a:0:{}s:9:\"createdAt\";O:22:\"Carbon\\CarbonImmutable\":3:{s:4:\"date\";s:26:\"2023-06-03 22:12:41.000000\";s:13:\"timezone_type\";i:3;s:8:\"timezone\";s:3:\"UTC\";}s:11:\"cancelledAt\";N;s:10:\"finishedAt\";N;s:16:\"updated_batch_id\";s:36:\"99534bfe-1359-4698-a3ce-96701e1de445\";}s:11:\"tagsChanges\";a:2:{s:7:\"removed\";a:0:{}s:5:\"added\";a:0:{}}}}s:28:\"\u0000*\u0000escapeWhenCastingToString\";b:0;}s:7:\"attempt\";i:0;s:5:\"delay\";O:25:\"Illuminate\\Support\\Carbon\":3:{s:4:\"date\";s:26:\"2023-06-03 22:12:52.783591\";s:13:\"timezone_type\";i:3;s:8:\"timezone\";s:3:\"UTC\";}}"
    },
    "telescope_uuid": null,
    "id": "rCFQJOBIQRM6ScbagN7wnaViB8884jol",
    "attempts": 0
}
```

Comment: did you restart the queue after the deployment?

Comment: Yes, the containers always restart If I publish a new release

Comment: You can try after clear cache: `php artisan cache:clear  &&
php artisan telescope:clear  &&  php artisan queue:restart`

Comment: This is actually the container start strategy. Anytime a new release gets deployed, the k8s deployment run `config:cache; migrate --force; telescope:clear; queue:work --memory=960 --timeout=1800;`